# moving mysql values to variables into bash for loops

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

i have a table that i want to query to that and get some values from my bash script and use it in while loop,when i use one column it works as a champ but i cant use more than one i get error like:

```
read: `IP, PL_Seq': not a valid identifier
```

here is my SELECT result

[image]

and here is may bash script

```
sql="SELECT IP,PL_Seq FROM mytabel WHERE FLAG=0 AND CIDR =24";
i=0
while IFS=$'\t' read IP, PL_Seq ;do
IP[$i]=$IP
PL_Seq[$i]=$PL_Seq
((i++))
echo $IP
echo $PL_Seq
done  < <(mysql TestDB -u $DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD -N -e "$sql")
```

Comment: "i cant use more than one" - what does that mean? Is this a MySQL problem, or a Bash problem?

Comment: more than one column like IP and PL_Seq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there, you just need to remove the comma from the line:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read IP, PL_Seq ;do
```

and so:

```
sql="SELECT IP FROM mytabel WHERE FLAG=0 AND CIDR =24";
i=0
while IFS=$'\t' read IP PL_Seq ;do
  IP[$i]=$IP
  PL_Seq[$i]=$PL_Seq
  ((i++))
  echo $IP
done  < <(mysql TestDB -u $DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD -N -e "$sql")
```

Comment: Thanks @Raman_Sailopal i do not get an error any more, but it just print out first column which is $IP and insted of $PL_Seq it prints space I think... 192.168.1.0

86.47.47.0

Comment: You are only using echo $IP inthe script. Add echo $PL_Seq underneath

Comment: Thank you for responding,that was my mistake in posting the code BUT after adding echo here is my $IP
echo here is my PL_Seq

i get this 
here is my 192.168.1.0 12
here is my 
here is my 86.47.47.0 11

which i want to get 
here is my 192.168.1.0
here is my 12
here is my 86.47.47.0 
here is my 11

Comment: It's probably you IFS variable that is the issue then.